# LaTeX problem: \addtocounter doesn't work with babel option

Tags: babel, counters

I am new on this forum, so I hope to write my question in the  right way.

I have a document in two parts (which is a model that I need many times), each part starting with page number 1. I must then write the total number of pages of the whole document. For this purpose, I want to use the command `\addtocounter`. The following code works:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{TotPages}
\addtocounter{TotPages}{\pageref{02}}
\addtocounter{TotPages}{\pageref{03}}
\pageref{02}+\pageref{03}=
\arabic{TotPages}
\section{title 01}
\newpage
\section{title 02}
\label{02}
\newpage
\section{title 03}
\label{03}
\end{document}
```

But with either `[french]`, `[francais]` or `[british]` option to `babel` package, it writes the error message

> *Missing number, treated as zero. \addtocounter{TotPages} \pageref{02}}*.

For example, the following code doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel} %only change
\begin{document}
\newcounter{TotPages}
\addtocounter{TotPages}{\pageref{02}}
\addtocounter{TotPages}{\pageref{03}}
\pageref{02}+\pageref{03}=
\arabic{TotPages}
\section{title 01}
\newpage
\section{title 02}
\label{02}
\newpage
\section{title 03}
\label{03}
\end{document}
```

I know that I could use the package calc, but I don't want if possible, since I need only this command in the whole document.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome, you are doing something completely wrong. What exactly are you  trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to make a document with two part, each part starting with page number one.

Comment: Package `lastpage`? `\setcounter{page}{1}`? I have no clue what you are trying to do.

Comment: Then I have to write the total number of pages of the whole document. For this purpose, I want to write a \label{01} at the end of the first part, and a \label{02} at the end of the second part. Then I want to get the total nomber of pages by adding the \pageref{01} and \pageref{02} numbers.

Comment: Christian Hupfer will be here soon and post an answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Am I that predictable? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know you for a while now ;-)

Comment: This is not related to `babel`, by the way

Comment: I also doubt that the first example is compilable

Comment: On my computer, my first code is compilable. Does that mean that there is a conflict between babel options and the \addtocounter command? Should I then report that to someone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer why `\addtocounter` fails with `\pageref`:

`\pageref` is not expandable, it can't be 'fed' to `\addtocounter` -- this macro expects a number value.

Apart from this issue, the addition of reference values to page is not giving what might be expected, since a `\pageref` appearing on page 5 and another one appearing on page 17 does not mean that the document has only 22 pages then; even if this would be the case, never rely on the output of a ref value, it could be a roman number or a letter as well.

Possible solutions:

- With the `lastpage` package it is possible to get the last page reference, but this does not work, if the page number is reset in the meantime → a wrong value is reported.
- With the `xassoccnt` package and its `\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}` the number of pages can be output with `\TotalValue{totalpages}` -- this is not influenced by a resetting of the page counter.
- Using `\usepackage[perpage,user,lastpage]{zref}` it is possible to get the total number of pages with `\zref[abspage]{LastPage}`.  (*Please do not confuse the LastPage label from `zref` with the `LastPage` label from the `lastpage` package -- they belong to different namespaces*)

Here's a 'tiny' document, showing the problems, the pageref can be extracted expandable with `\getpagerefnumber` from `refcount`, for example  -- it is only added in order to show that the counting with `\pageref` is logically wrong.

The document has 6 pages, only `\TotalValue` or `\zref[abspage]{LastPage}` report the correct value.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[francais]{babel} %only change


\usepackage[perpage,user,lastpage]{zref}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\part}{\pagenumbering{arabic}\clearpage}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcounter{TotPages}

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{TotPages}{\getpagerefnumber{02}}
\addtocounter{TotPages}{\getpagerefnumber{03}}


The number of pages in this beautiful document: \TotalValue{totalpages} pages! 

whereas \verb!\pageref{Lastpage}! reports \pageref{LastPage} pages!. 

With \texttt{zref} you get \zref[abspage]{LastPage} pages!


Values reported with sum up of references: \pageref{02}+\pageref{03}= \arabic{TotPages} pages!

\part{First} 

\section{title 01}
\clearpage
\section{title 02}
\label{02}
\clearpage

\blindtext

\part{Second} 
\section{title 03} \label{03}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! If I understand right, \makeatletter \pretocmd{\part}{\page-numbering{arabic}\clearpage}{}{} sets the page counter as a number. Should there not be a \makeatother afterwards?

Anyway, I tried the xassoccnt package, which looks out to be the best solution, since zref could leads to confusions with lastpage package, which I also use. I copied and pasted your code, but I unfortunately get the error message Undefined control sequence. \DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters. Did I make something wrong?

Comment: @Garulfo: I forgot the `\makeatother`, sorry. `\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters` is an addition in v1.2. (current version is 1.6), from 2017/03/03. If this does not work, `\DeclareTotalDocumentCounter{totalpages}\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}` works for older versions. In my point of view, `zref` and `lastpage` do not interfere

Comment: I tried, it seems to works, but then other problems appears. I'll try tomorrow to analyze that and post then an new message.

Comment: So I tried again, but when I only add \usepackage{xassoccnt}, without any other commands, a new error appears with labels: Undefined control sequence. \label{LastPagePart01}. Does it mean that there is a conflict between xassoccnt and labels?

Comment: No, there shold be no conflict as long as you load xassoccnt very late

Comment: Then I have to take some more time. Is it possible to leave this post as it is, and continue it in maybe one week or so?

Comment: Or I do better: I consider my question as answered, since your solution works well in my short examples. And if I don't manage to solve the new problems, I will open another post. So again, thanks a lot for your help!!!!!

Comment: @Garulfo: If this question is answered (and it is! ;-), please consider to accept my answer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see these votes... It is done now.